# Deserialize json with JSON.NET, but keep original json of particular class on additional field

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some 3rd party data provider with a nested data structure like this

```
{
    "response": {
        "...": "...",
        "transactions": [
            {
                "well-known-field": 123,
                "new-unknown-field": 456,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, I have a corresponding class structure for deserialization. On a transaction level the class have only well-known fields. But on each transaction there are some dynamic fields or just new fields that I prefer to have at least in logs or even in mongodb document. I known I can put `JRaw` for any of those fields, but I don't know the names of future fields and I just prefer to have full raw transaction itself. Is it possible to have additional `JObject` of transaction itself inside `Transaction` class?

I suppose, I can do this by deserializing via second data structure where List of transactions is just  a `List<JObject>` and then just go foreach transaction in first result and set a `JObject Raw` field from second result but that looks silly. May be there are some extension or built-in ability to achieve that in Newtonsoft JSON.Net in one pass?

```cs
public class Transaction
{
    public decimal WellKnownField { get; set; }
    public JObject RawTransaction { get; set; }
}
```

UPD: I think I'd better prefer `string RawTransaction` instead. That would be perfect for serialization diagnostics, for logging original raw json and for attempts to re-apply serialization itself in case if we change some attributes or settings, or default values.

Comment: You can create types dynamically in C# (via TypeBuilder class) but that isn't recommended so you'd better stick with a key-value pair in this case. It would be more performance-wise and less complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to make your `Transaction` class look like this:

```
public class Transaction {

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public String Id {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
    ...
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<String,Object> AdditionalData {get; set;}
}
```

This way you can both benefit from `Strongly Typed` information which are known at compile time and those which are dynamic.

Comment: I think you forgot [JsonExtensionData] attribute. Yes, this is very very close indeed... Except that I'd better have full object. This is because of transaction class evolution. Before I add new field to the class, I'll have 'new-unknown-field' in additional data, but after I add it, that would not appear in new incoming transactions. And this makes upgrade logic more complex.
Also - I realized that I can put this attribute over JObject field (because it is IDictionary<string, JToken>)

Comment: @DmitryGusarov: 'I think you forgot [JsonExtensionData] attribute.': Yes that's right, I forgot about that :P!

Comment: I finally ended up going back to [JsonExtensionData]. I did this when I realized that I can do the same while inserting in mongodb using [BsonExtraElements]. So, all my undeclared columns falls into [JsonExtensionData][BsonIgnore] field and then it converts on a getter of [BsonExtraElements][JsonIgnore] field. This solves my initial task completely - I have entire dynamic object in database and I can incrementally declare known fields in C# without database upgrades

Comment: @DmitryGusarov: Mongo is a great choice, you also taught me something now as I didn't know about the `[BsonExtraElements]`. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I eventually came up with:

```
public class TransactionResponse
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public JObject AdditionalData { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public JValue RawTransaction { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        var ser = (JValue)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        AdditionalData.Merge(ser);
        RawTransaction = ser;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

That gives a full view of original object, and I can even put it to mongo as a string using `RawTransaction.ToString()` for any future analysis. Not perfect because it is tokenized and I don't see the original whitespaces and cr lf in json but that's probably too much...

Comment: Also I don't like that I get integer 0 and boolean false even for those fields that never been in original json... :(